Finding the infinite sum $4+9x+21x^2+51x^3+129x^4+\cdots$
Recently I was shown the following question from the 1873 Algebra (honors) Matriculation examination (which is a paper students in their final year of high school would have taken as part of their university admissions process), set by Professor Wilson of The University of Melbourne:

Find the sum to infinity and the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the series
$$4+9x+21x^2+51x^3+129x^4+\cdots$$

After some playing around with the numbers and realizing the sequence was neither arithmetic nor geometric, I have been able to show
$$t_{n+1}=\left(2t_n+3^n\right)x^n$$
Where I am stuck is turning this into a formula for the sum to infinity.
Is there a standard way to do this?

Are you sure this is a high school exam, and not a university exam?

Yes, it was the entry to university exam from the October Term of 1873. There were two levels, pass and honors. This was the honors exam which was for students applying to study the honors stream at the university. Most of the other questions are doable, this one has had me stuck for over 24 hours. Hence asking it here.

That recursion is a big stretch given the limited data.  there's a quartic that interpolates the data....is that less probable?

It seems that you intend $t_n$ to be the coefficient of $x^n$. If so, then your expression of $t_{n+1}=(2\times t_n+3^n)\times x^n$ should be something like $t_{n+1}{\color{red}{\times x^{n+1}}}=(2\times t_n+3^n)\times x^n$ instead.

@JohnOmielan I see what you are saying and agree that it is not clear. I do not know if it was meant that way in the exam or not. I originally assumed that the $x^n$ was part of the term, but then decided that there will be restrictions on what values of $x$ allow the series to converge.

Note I made a mistake in the definition I suggested. The RHS $x^n$ factor should either be changed to $x^{n+1}$, or not use my extra suggested LHS factor of $x^{n+1}$ and remove the $x^n$ factor. This then would match the $5$ terms shown. With $t_0=4$, your definition gives $t_1=(2\times 4+3^0)\times x^1=9$, but then $t_2=(2\times 9+3^1)\times x^1=21x$, which doesn't match anything shown. Next, there's $t_3=(2\times 21x+3^2)\times x^2=42x^3+9x^2$, then $t_4=(2\times(42x^3+9x^2)+3^3)\times x^3=84x^6+18x^5+27x^3$, etc.

$t_n-3^n=3\times2^n$ makes it easy.

@GerryMyerson that is brilliant. If you want/have time to write this as a formal answer that would be great.

@GerryMyerson gave the key
$$t_n=3^n+3\times2^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n,x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3x)^n+3\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n$$  Just finish and simplify

I won't have time to write anything up for about the next day-and-a-half, Red Five, but you're welcome to write it up if you can't wait.

All good @GerryMyerson. It is yours to write up if you wish. I've been playing around with it a bit today regarding the convergence - am I correct that the series will always converge if $\frac{-1}{3}<x<\frac{1}{3}$?

@lulu an interesting idea. Given any polynomial of degree 4 or higher can model this set of coefficients I decided that this was unlikely and some recursion formula was more likely. Unfortunately, given the age of these papers, there are no solutions, answers or examiners' reports anywhere to check against.

Once you get to $t_{n+1}-2t_n=3^n$, there is a standard way to proceed.
First, you look at the corresponding homogeneous recurrence, $t_{n+1}-2t_n=0$. This has the obvious solution $t_n=2^nA$, where $A$ is an arbitrary constant.
Then, you try to find any one solution to the full recurrence, $t_{n+1}-2t_n=3^n$. The general theory of these things tells you that there is a number $B$ such that $t_n=3^nB$ is a solution. Substituting that in gives you $3^{n+1}B-2\times3^nB=3^n$, which reduces to $B=1$, so $t_n=3^n$ is what's called a particular solution to the recurrence.
Now the general theory tells you that the general solution of the original recurrence is the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence and the particular solution, so $t_n=2^nA+3^n$.
It remains to work out what $A$ is. Letting $n=0$, we get $4=A+1$, so $A=3$, so $t_n=3\times2^n+3^n$.
Whether these methods would have been known to Australian high school students in 1873, I cannot say. I had mixed success teaching them to Australian university students from 1987 to 2018. In any event, they can be found in lots of textbooks with the phrase, "Discrete Mathematics" in the title, also on dozens of websites by searching for "linear recurrences".

Many thanks. As to what was and was not known in high schools in 1873 I would suspect it was entirely driven by what the universities were examining. The NSW matriculation papers from the time seem to be very similar to Oxford and Cambridge entry examinations, and I assume Victoria did a similar thing.

if you want an expression of $t_n$,
You can prove by induction that:
$t_n = 2^n t_0 + \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (2^{n-k} \cdot 3^{k-1}) $
I just tried with base cases and got out a formula using induction.
Factoring $2^n$ and $3^{-1}$ from the sum will get you something geometric which might help you get a finer expression of $t_n$.
Edit:
Simplifying the sum above, you'll get:
$t_n = 3 \cdot 2^n +3^n$
Then, the function becomes (as the others have seen too):
$f(x) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( 3 \cdot 2^k +3^k \right)\cdot x^k = 3 \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k x^k + \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^k x^k$
You already checked that the function converges for $|x|<\frac{1}{3}$, so for those values, your function would be equal to :
$f(x) = \frac{3}{1-2x}+\frac{1}{1-3x} \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in ]\frac{-1}{3};\frac{1}{3}[$
Which is derived from the taylor series for usual functions.

Thanks - looks to be on the right track. Can you now show how to find the sum to infinity?

edited my answer

I like it - but I'm not sure why a Taylor Series is required and we can't just use the sum of two infinite geometric series. I got the same final result but didn't use a Taylor Series. Not saying a Taylor Series is wrong, just curious why you chose that approach.

Its the same, I called it taylor series because, as I am not a native english speaker, I forgot the other name, which would be geometric series
